# Permanently removing binary files from GitLab repos

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

We have a GitLab-hosted repo at work that contains some large binary files that we'd like to remove. I know of tools such as BFG Repo-Cleaner which will remove a file from a Git repository.

We often refer to specific commit IDs in GitLab.  Would running BFG Repo-Cleaner mess these up?

If so, is there a better way to clean a repo that wouldn't mess these up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We often refer to specific commit IDs in GitLab.

Although git history can't be modified without changing all subsequent commit ids, the BFG does a few things that will help with the change:

1. As it's cleaning your repo, the BFG *also* [updates any object ids it finds in commit messages](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/35224db/bfg-library/src/test/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cleaner/ObjectIdSubstitutorSpec.scala#L53-L55) with their *new ids*. If you are deleting [private data](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/35224db/bfg/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cli/CLIConfig.scala#L175), it's a [straight substitution](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/35224db/bfg-library/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cleaner/ObjectIdSubstitutor.scala#L36-L38), if you're just deleting big files (ie the commit ids themselves *don't* imply sensitive information), the text in your commit message becomes [`"$newId [formerly $oldId]"`](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/35224db/bfg-library/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cleaner/ObjectIdSubstitutor.scala#L40-L42) and in addition, a [`Former-commit-id:`](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/35224db/bfg-library/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cleaner/commits.scala#L50-L58) footer will be added to the bottom of [all modified commit messages](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Former-commit-id%22+-bfg).
2. The BFG also creates a `object-id-map.old-new.txt` file under the `repo-name.bfg-report` directory every time it runs. In principle, I believe this file could be used on a GitLab repo so that other references to commit ids could be fixed too.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).*

Answer (score 1):

> We often refer to specific commit IDs in GitLab. Would running BFG Repo-Cleaner mess these up?

A git commit id is built from the hash of the commit contents and the id of the previous commit.  This means that *any* operation that modifies your history will result in a (a) a new commit id for whatever commit you modify and (b) a new commit id for *every descendant commit*.

There is no way to modify the history of your repository without generation a new sequence of commit ids.